# pbcopy in Python to copy to the clipboard on OSX?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pbcopy

I am receiving the following error when trying to use `pbcopy` to add the output to the clipboard. I tried different variations of the command and still no luck.
Does anyone have any ideas where I may have failed?

Error Screenshot:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# This script creates a secure password using all available key combinations.

import secrets , string, os

def prRed(skk): print("\033[91m {}\033[00m" .format(skk))

chars = string.ascii_letters+string.punctuation+string.digits # Cleaner way of assigning variable

print()
pwd_length = int(input('Enter the length of the desired password: '))

print()
print('[+] ' + 'Your secure password is:')
print()

for n in range(1):
    output = ""
    for i in range(pwd_length):
        next_index = secrets.SystemRandom().randrange(len(chars))
        output = output + chars[next_index]
    prRed(os.system("echo '%s' | pbcopy" % output))
print()
```

Comment: You have included `string.punctuation` in allowable characters which may have let a closing `'` into your password that you echo inside `'`.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up manually assigning the string.punctuation to exclude quotes. However, instead of cheating, Id like to learn how to include punctuation in a way that doesn't break the pbcopy code, can this be done a different way?

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend using many punctuation characters in a password to be honest - maybe just dash and underscore - firstly because different apps have different allowable characters and secondly because they'll cause you hassle when you try and use them on command-line to mount shares, login to servers and generally parsing things...